# Move camera to current location OnMapReady (Android Google Maps API)

Tags: java, android, google-maps, google-maps-api-3, maps

How do I make the camera move to the current user location as soon as the map opens?
This is how i require the permission for the location:

```
if (ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION)
            == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
        mMap.setMyLocationEnabled(true);
    } else {
        ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(this,new String[]{Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION},MY_LOCATION_REQUEST_CODE);
    }
```

This is in the onCreate function

Comment: Try my edited answer.

Comment: Did my answer help you? if yes please mark it as the helpful answer so everybody with the same problem can see here is a solution. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This code should center the map to the position, you need the geolocation.

```
CameraPosition cameraPosition = new CameraPosition.Builder()
.target(**LatLng object of your position**)      // Sets the center of the map to Geolocation
.zoom(17)                   // Sets the zoom
.bearing(90)                // Sets the orientation of the camera to east
.tilt(30)                   // Sets the tilt of the camera to 30 degrees
.build();                   // Creates a CameraPosition from the builder

map.animateCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newCameraPosition(cameraPosition));
```

**EDIT:**
First we create some variables on the top:

```
private boolean localizationAllowed; //here we save if the user has allowed to locate him.
private boolean localizationRequested = false; // here we save if the localization has already requested.
```

create some private methods:

```
private void enableLocationUpdates(String provider) {
        if(!localizationRequested) {
            if (ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED && ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
                ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(this, new String[]{Manifest.permission.READ_CONTACTS},
                        MY_PERMISSIONS_REQUEST_ACCESS_FINE_LOCATIONS);
                localizationRequested = true;
            }
        }
        if (provider != null && localizationAllowed) {
            locationManager.requestLocationUpdates(provider, 1000, 0, this);
        }
    }

    private void disableLocationUpdates() {
        if(!localizationRequested) {
            if (ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED && ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
                ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(this, new String[]{Manifest.permission.READ_CONTACTS},
                        MY_PERMISSIONS_REQUEST_ACCESS_FINE_LOCATIONS);
                localizationRequested = true;
            }
        }
        if (locationManager != null && localizationAllowed){
          locationManager.removeUpdates(this);
        }
    }
private void initLocalisation(){
    if(localizationAllowed) {
        LocationManager service = (LocationManager) getSystemService(LOCATION_SERVICE);
        if (service != null) {
            boolean enabled = service
                    .isProviderEnabled(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER);

            // check if enabled and if not send user to the GSP settings
            // Better solution would be to display a dialog and suggesting to
            // go to the settings
            if (!enabled) {
                Intent intent = new Intent(Settings.ACTION_LOCATION_SOURCE_SETTINGS);
                startActivity(intent);
            }

            // Get the location manager
            locationManager = (LocationManager) getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);
            // Define the criteria how to select the locatioin provider -> use
            // default
            Criteria criteria = new Criteria();
            provider = locationManager.getBestProvider(criteria, false);

            enableLocationUpdates(provider);
        }
    }
}
```

Initialize the localization:

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
 //your onCreate methods
 initLocalisation();
 //your onCreate methods
}
```

onMapReady to start localization when the map is ready

```
@Override
public void onMapReady(GoogleMap googleMap) {
    mMap = googleMap;
    Location location = getLastLocation();
    if (location != null) {
        LatLng you = new LatLng(location.getLatitude(), location.getLongitude());
        mMap.animateCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLngZoom(you, 17f));
    }
}
```

Comment: Actually I need the geolocation part. I know how to move the camera, but I don't know how to get the LatLng of the users current location.